# upgrading to jre 1.7 update 40 causes inablility to start Tomcat 7.0.37 and 7.0.42 main page with client authenatication

Tags: tomcat7

On Windows Server 2008, Tomcat 7.0.37 and JRE 7 update 21 run fine with client authentication using the following server.xml file entry:

```
<Connector port="8443" crlFile="conf/mvca.crl" truststoreType="JKS"  truststorePass="changeit" truststoreFile="c:/program files/java/jre7/lib/security/cacerts" keystorePass="maxview" keystoreFile="conf/mvkey.ks" sslProtocol="TLS" clientAuth="true" secure="true" scheme="https" maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" protocol="HTTP/1.1"/>
```

After upgrading to JRE 7 update 40, I can no longer bring up the tomcat main page at:
https:/mymachine.mydomain.com:8443

I see the same error when using JRE 7 update 40 and Tomcat 7.0.42.

There is no HTTP error code. The error message displayed is:
Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage

The Tomcat7 service starts.

If client authentication is turned off, the main page will operate.

I don't see any relevant error messages in the Tomcat logs.

What steps can I take to shed more light on the issue to determine the root cause?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if it's to do with some of the crypto changes in Update 40 RSA keys < 1024 have been disabled.

From the release notes:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u40-relnotes-2004172.html#newft

> Default x.509 Certificates Have Longer Key Length Starting from 7u40,
>   the use of x.509 certificates with RSA keys less than 1024 bits in
>   length is restricted. This restriction is applied via the Java
>   Security property, jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms. The default value
>   of jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms is now as follows:
>
> jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, RSA keySize < 1024  In order to
>   avoid the compatibility issue, users who use X.509 certificates with
>   RSA keys less than 1024 bits, are recommended to update their
>   certificates with stronger keys. As a workaround, at their own risk,
>   users can adjust the key size to permit smaller key sizes through the
>   security property jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms.

A quick diff  in `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security` shows:

```
$ diff java.security /opt/jdk1.7.0_21/jre/lib/security/java.security

149,152c149,150
<                com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.,\
<                com.sun.org.glassfish.,\
<                org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.,\
<                oracle.jrockit.jfr.
---
>                com.sun.org.glassfish.
>
186,189c184,185
<                    com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.,\
<                    com.sun.org.glassfish.,\
<                    org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.,\
<                    oracle.jrockit.jfr.
---
>                    com.sun.org.glassfish.
>
402c398
< jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, RSA keySize < 1024
---
> jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=MD2



jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, RSA keySize < 1024
```

Strange that there are no logs indicating what is wrong.

Comment: In the java.security file, restoring the entry to just 

jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=MD2 resolved the problem.